# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzcx(Landroid/content

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Friends Help me to solve this error..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0ncy.jpg)

Comment: what is your error

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzcx(Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbth; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbth; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbth' appears in /data/app/com.project.assassin.chatapp-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes16.dex)

Comment: go to `Build -> Clean & rebuild` your project and try again

Comment: bro i try it ...but again it app crushs

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule in your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:10.0.1'
```

> For latest version

Add this rule in your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.4.2'
```

And change all your firebase dependency version to `11.4.2`

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
```

Make sure that you added these rules to your root-level `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but i cant find any error in that image @Harish

Comment: Add the first rule i mentioned above and re-sync your project. Check weather you are getting the same error @Harish